# How do you rotate a text

Tags: geogebra

[There is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQP0go7p5HA) on how to rotate an object around a point but I fail to select the text.

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to do the same thing and saw your question before figuring this out.

### 1. The "Geogebra Way"

In the Algebra Perspective enter the following [RotateText](https://www.geogebra.org/manual/en/RotateText_Command) commands in the Input box at the bottom:

- RotateText["Rotated text using degrees.", 45°]
  RotateText["Rotated text using radians.", 0.785398]

In the Construction Protocol view, this is represented by

- "rotatebox{45}{ \text{Rotated text using degrees.} }"
  "rotatebox{44.9999999}{ \text{Rotated text using radians.} }"

Note that the radian form of the RotateText command is converted to degrees in the construction step.  So this creates an graphical object that renders the text in a LaTeX "rotatebox".  It's rather strange that the system doesn't have a tool to create rotateable text.

You can attach the text to an object via the object's Properties->Position->Starting Point.  Only certain types of objects can be used, and the text can only be placed/moved underneath the object, which is odd.  You can get around this by creating a line segment, attaching the rotateable text object to a desired end-point on the line segment *above* the location you want the final text, and then hiding the line segment.

### 2. A better, "undocumented" Geogebra method!

One can actually use LaTeX in captions of objects.  Here's how you would enter the text:

- $\rotatebox{45}{ \text{Rotated text using standard text box!} }$

A nice thing about this is the caption can be easily placed above the object.  Notice that LaTeX commands are surrounded by the dollar sign.  Also notice that there is a backslash as part of the **\rotatebox** command.

Also, one can use the standard text tool to do the same thing.  This has the advantage that the text can be dynamic!  Create some text anywhere.  Then edit it's properties on the Text tab.  Check the LaTeX checkbox, and enter the following for the text:

- $\rotatebox{45}{ \text{} }$

Then inside the \text{} brackets, select an object.  The text will be updated with the object's value.  Or a combined form:

- $\rotatebox{45}{ \text{"The value is:" + `SliderObject`} }$

I've tried to put an object in the "degreees" field, but could not get that to work.

Comment: Also, FYI, for help with English, I recommend [ell.stackexchange.com](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).  It's designed specifically to help English Language Learners, and they are very nice. :)

Comment: Some References **(1)** https://www.geogebra.org/manual/en/Labels_and_Captions 
**(2)** http://www.malinc.se/math/geogebra/dynamictextandlatexen.php **(3)** 
https://www.geogebra.org/manual/en/LaTeX

Answer (score 0):

Use the RotateText command like this:

```
RotateText("What ever text you want", angle)
```